# Swift: Set protocol's associated type in argument / member variable

Tags: swift, swift5, swift-protocols, associated-types

I'm trying to create a generic protocol that can be reused in various parts throughout my application. Previously I've hardcoded `KeyValueStore` to only use `String` and `Int` for `Key` and `Value` respectively. I ran into an issue where I want a different consumer, class `ConsumerB`, to use `KeyValueStore` with `Key`/`Value` being `Int`/`Int` respectively.

```
protocol KeyValueStore {
    associatedtype Key
    associatedtype Value
    func get(key: Key) -> Value
    func set(key: Key, value: Value)
}
```

For the original implementation, I had two classes the conform to the protocol. `UserDefaultsStore` was used to store data during runtime and `MemoryKeyValueStore` was used in unit testing.

```
class UserDefaultsStore: KeyValueStore {
    func get(key: String) -> Int { return 0
        // Implementation
    }
    
    func set(key: String, value: Int) {
        // Implementation
    }
}

class MemoryKeyValueStore: KeyValueStore {
    var values: [String: Int] = [:]
    func get(key: String) -> Int { return values[key]! }
    func set(key: String, value: Int) { values[key] = value}
}
```

Since they both used `KeyValueStore` with hardcoded types I could provide a store implementation at runtime.

```
class ConsumerA {
    var keyValueStore: KeyValueStore
    
    init(store: KeyValueStore) {
        keyValueStore = store
    }
  
    func example() {
        keyValueStore.set(key: "Hello", value: 5)
    }
}
```

After adding the associated types, I get the error below. It makes sense that while compiling `ConsumerA` , there is no way to know what type `Key` and `Value` take on in the `KeyValueStore` argument and member variable. However after poking around, I could not seem to find a clear answer on **how to properly declare what types `Key` and `Value` should be in the `ConsumerA` class.**

In the `example` function, it is clear it would use `String` and `Int`, but how do I set the argument/member variable to only allow classes that conform to `KeyValueStore` and have `Key`/`Value` set to `String`/`Int`?

```
Protocol 'KeyValueStore' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

**Edit:**
I ended up going a different route based on [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/swift-protocols-with-associated-types-and-generics-373b2927baed) medium article I found later in the evening.
While it seems like Swift should just natively provide a way to declare a protocol with associated types as a argument/variable type here is the work around.

```
class AnyKeyValueStore<Key, Value>: KeyValueStore {
    private let _set: (Value?, Key) -> Void
    private let _object: (Key) -> Value?
    
    init<U: KeyValueStore>(_ keyValueStore: U) where U.Key == Key, U.Value == Value {
        _set = keyValueStore.set
        _object = keyValueStore.object
    }
    
    func set(value: Value?, forKey key: Key) {
        _set(value, key)
    }
    
    func object(forKey key: Key) -> Value? {
        return _object(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the solution, wish it worked with actors but actors cannot inherit from classes or other actors for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConsumerA` needs to be generic. Replace `ModuleName` with your actual module name.

```swift
class ConsumerA<KeyValueStore: ModuleName.KeyValueStore>
where KeyValueStore.Key == String, KeyValueStore.Value == Int {
```

---

Also, your method pair should be a subscript instead.

```swift
subscript(key: Key) -> Value { get set }
```

```swift
keyValueStore["Hello"] = 5
```

Comment: For anyone that may have overlooked like I did. Going back to my tests, it looks like I incorrectly used `KeyValueStore` when referencing `Key` and `Value` in the where clause instead of the generic.

Comment: I would also return an optional Value `subscript(key: Key) -> Value?`

Comment: @LeoDabus I ended up using the `AnyKeyValueStore` method above and implemented the subscripting exactly as you suggested in a protocol extension.